# How to create a download link in the way that it will work on ios and android devices

Tags: android, ios, download

Wanna create download link to file but it works only in desktop browsers not in IOS and Android Devices.

Any ideas how i can achieve that with php, jquery etc.?

Here is what i tried

```
<?php
 $filename = $_GET['file'];
 if (isset($filename)) 
{
// Prevents someone from trying to access something that is not in the same directory as this script
if(substr_count($filename,"/") > 0)
{
die('error');
}; 
$len = filesize($filename);
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.$len);
readfile($filename);
}
else
{
die('No file specified.'); 
};
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'not in iOS and Android devices'. what is the way you're displaying this link on iOS and Android?

Comment: @Anahit DEV : web links or web api's are not restricted to client platforms :) web services run on server :) may it be php, java, ruby or python :) they all run at server not at client :) all you have to do is to read the file and stream it using ur php script or java rest api or servlets or any other server side code you can think of :)

Comment: and at your client apps hit the api read the content chunk by chunk and store it in a file and thats how you download it :) and now if your client is just browsers and not custom app, all android browsers are capable of downloading the content :) as per safari in ios is concerned :) I dont think it downloads any of the content :) So if your browser is not allowing you to download the content, you can't do anything at server end :) and lastly once you write API test it in postman plugin by apple :)

Comment: See the code in my edited question @SandeepBhandari. With that php script it works on desktop browsers, even on android but not in IOS devices like iphone, it just opened in new tab

Comment: @anahit-dev : thats what i said in my second comment buddy :) you cant doanything to make it download at iOS devices :) It is the restriction imposed by apple :)

Comment: Hmm i get it. So no way! @SandeepBhandari

Comment: In order to understand how safari works you can have a look at this link :) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/downloading-and-uploading-files-through-safari-ios . as link clearly says, the file you dump,  will be downloaded and saved in the cache of safari and not to file system :) safari acts as a restricted app :) and wont allow you to save downloaded file content to file system if its not image or video :) mp3 files will be stream but wont be saved :)

Comment: Thanks for the detaild and proper feedback @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @anahit-dev: you are always welcome buddy :) Don take my words for it though :) I am an iOS developer with little knowledge in java rest API development :) Whatever I wrote is based on my little experience in both the platform :) please read the link I posted carefully :) I never seen safari allowing any download :)